# Extracting main subject from a sentence in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, nltk, spacy, data-extraction

I am trying to extract the main subject from a sentence contained in a text file. For example, the file contains data as given below

```
I never used tobacco
They smoke tobacco
I do not like today's weather
Good weather
Exercise 3 to 4 times a week
No exercise
Family history of Cancer
No Cancer
,,· Alcohol use
Amazing football match
Pathetic football match
Has Depression
```

I have to extract the main subject and print it as follows:

```
I never used tobacco | Tobacco | False
They smoke tobacco | Tobacco | True
I do not like today's weather | Weather | False
Good weather | Weather | True
Exercise 3 to 4 times a week | Exercise | True
No exercise | Exercise | False
Family history of Cancer | Cancer | True
No Cancer | Cancer | False
,,· Alcohol use. | Alcohol | True
Amazing football match | Football Match| True
Pathetic football match | Football Match | False
Has Depression | Depression | True
```

I am trying Spacy for it but not able to get the desired output.  I tokenized the sentences using Spacy then used part of speech tagging to extract the nouns but still not getting what is required.
Can anyone help that how it could be done?

Comment: Have you tried Spacy's dependency parser? That might be a way to extract only the top level noun, which could be closer to what you expect.
Aside from that, are your boolean values somehow related to sentiment (i.e. present negations or confirmations?)

Comment: @dennlinger Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I used.In this way:
        for word in doc.noun_chunks:
            print(word.text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not an exact solution to it but the below code which I used is somewhat helpful:

```
negatedwords = read_words_from_file('false.txt') # file containing all the negation words
#read_words_from_file() will read words from file

from collections import Counter
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')

count = Counter(line.split())
negated_word_found = False
for key, val in count.items():
    key = key.rstrip('.,?!\n') # removing punctuations
    if key in negatedwords :
        negated_word_found= True

if negated_word_found== True:
    file_write.write("False")
else:
    file_write.write("True")

file_write.write(" | ")
document = nlp(line)

for word in document:
    look_for_word = word.text
    word_pos = word.pos_
    if ((word_pos =="NOUN" or word_pos =="ADJ" or word_pos == "PROPN" ) and look_for_word!="use" ): #The pos_ tag for 'use' is showed as NOUN  
        file_write.write(look_for_word)
        file_write.write(' ')

false.txt
never
Never
no
No
NO
not
NOT
Not
NEVER
don't
Don't
DON'T
```